# Request header is too big, getting an empty response from the server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx

I'm sending a large header (5k) to a node application proxied by Nginx. I get an empty response from the server (no headers, no data). I don't see any errors in the nginx logs. If I manually decrease the large header by a bit, I get a response as expected. I've tried adding these lines to my nginx config:

```
client_header_buffer_size 32k;
large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;

...

proxy_buffer_size          128k;
proxy_buffers              4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;
```

No change. I've also tried adding this flag when running the node application:

```
--max-http-header-size=64000
```

Didn't work. I've grep'ed all of my /var/log's for "header" and for my IP address. Not seeing anything suspicious.

Any idea where I might look for errors? Any nginx or node solutions to try? Or is this possibly caused by something else (e.g. lower level networking settings in the OS)?

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem on CentOS 7, updating to nginx 1.21.0 solved the problem.